# invalid use of typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef

To save some space in my code, I made this typedef:

```
typedef clients.members.at(selectedTab) currentMember;
```

however, g++ gives me this error:

```
error: expected initializer before '.' token
```

I figure that I'm misusing typedef, since `clients.members.at(selectedTab)` is a function call and not a type.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: save space to loose on readability ? just wondering ?

Comment: You have already answered your own question

Comment: Are you trying to get a function-local abbrevation? Is `selectedTab` expected to change between calls of it?

Comment: @ other Max:  It's a very localized typedef.  The typedef and all the code that uses it spans across about fifteen lines, so to me it makes it much more readable and concise.

@ Ed Swangren: not really.  I may know why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the code you have. Making it shorter reduces readability and right now it does not seem all that long, so making it shorter won't save too much space. Plus if 'selectedTab' changes and you have 'currentMember' already set, then it may become invalid.

Comment: @Max:  +1 for being wary of macros.

Comment: I don't think this is valid. It looks like you're trying to do something similar to delphi's *with* operator. The closest thing to it is reference. See answer of Georg Fritzsche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is used function-local and neither `clients.members` nor `selectedTab` change between its uses, just use references. E.g.:

```
Member& currentMember = clients.members.at(selectedTab);
currentMember.foo();
currentMember.bar();
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than what I was trying to do, so I'll go with this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to create a macro.

```
#define currentMember clients.members.at(selectedTab)
```

Though depending on how it's used, a simple function could be much better.

Comment: That makes it work, though I'm a bit wary of macros.  I'll just deal with the less concise code.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Like Chuck said, if you're wary of macros, just make a simple function `currentMember()` that returns `clients.members.at(selectedTab)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x, you can do

```
decltype(clients.members.at(selectedTab)) currentMember(clients.members.at(selectedTab));
```

However, what you're doing is fundamentally not possible. You're trying to get a value and make it a type. That's just not doable. Consider the following code:

```
typedef clients.members.at(selectedTab) currentMember;
currentMember a;
```

What on earth is a, and what does it do? You're going to have to explain more what you want.